# Strange behaviour of php using wamp

Tags: php, wampserver

I have been using wamp server do build small websites with php for a long time.. but this morning something strange just happend :

here is my `home.html` file :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello world</p>'; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

and here is what I get when I display the page :

```
Hello world
'; ?>
```

And when I display the source code, here is what I get :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Test PHP</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php echo '<p>Hello world</p>'; ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

It seems to be a very stupid problem where the php code is not interpreted by the server.. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You saved the filename as .html

Use .php instead of .html it will interrupt.

Comment: As I said... it seemed to be a very stupid problem... It always when it is obvious that I can't see it :/